# How do I access the response value for a fetch/http call using Promise.allSettled?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I'm trying to use Promise.allSettled to call 3 urls and process the results when all are finished. However, I cannot seem to access the value of the responses, which are JSON. Here is my code:

```
let urlList = ['http...', 'http...', 'http...'];

let fetches = urlList.map(url => fetch(url));
Promise.allSettled(fetches)
    .then((results) => { // (*)

        results.forEach((result, num) => {

            if (result.status == "fulfilled") {
                //result.value is a response object and I cannot seem to access the response.body or the actual text/json value of the response
                // in chrome developer tools, I can see the results I want, just can't seem to read them here
                console.log(result.value);
            }
            else if (result.status == "rejected") {
                console.log(`Failed Calling: ${urls[num]}\n\treason: ${result.reason}`);
            }

        });

        //call other method with combined results...
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
    });
```

console.log output:
[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
let fetches = urlList.map(url => fetch(url));
```

to this:

```
let fetches = urlList.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json()));
```

That way your `Promise.allSettled()` will give you an array of promises that resolve to your final value, not just to the response headers object so your `result.value` property will be the final value for each promise.